# how to remove "\'"?

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I'm trying to remove `\'` from an string

```
 string temp = "[['90\'','','Delay in match Cédric Kanté (Sochaux) because of an injury.','away']]";

 temp = Regex.Replace(temp, @"\\'", "");  >> still have ' mark  [['90'','','...']
```

I've tried many ways but failed.

Thanks

Comment: that's correct, sorry not to be clear

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do: `.Replace(temp, @"\\", "");`

Comment: @"\\" remove \ but what about ', it's still there. ['90\'','start delay','Delay xxxx'],['23\'','','abcd'], i can't replace '' => ' since there're '' in other []

Comment: For that you can do `.Replace(temp, @"\\'", "");`

Comment: sorry, i made a wrong test. can't work that way. your code is actually my above code.

Answer (score 0):

It is in a form that can be parsed by [json serilaizers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx). No need for Regex.

```
string temp = @"[['90\'','','Delay in match Cédric Kanté (Sochaux) because of an injury.','away']]";

var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<List<string>> listOfList = js.Deserialize<List<List<string>>>(temp);

foreach (var item in listOfList[0])
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```